# AOP-style Mixin Composition in Scala

Tags: scala, aop, mixins

I'm trying to use mixins to get AOP/interceptor-like style of programming.

Here's my code:

```
trait X {
  def run
}

trait Y extends X {
  abstract override def run = {
    println("hi")
    super.run
  }
}

object Z extends X with Y {
  def run = println("bye")
}
```

I get the following error when trying to compile:

> method run needs `override' modifier

What am I doing wrong here? I tried to add the 'override' modifier, but than it gives me:

> method run needs `abstract override' modifiers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you can do it, is to define base functionality in a class `A` extending the base `X`, and to provide an object (or a class) that mixes `A` and `Y` (and all the other traits you may define):

```
trait X {
  def run
}

trait Y extends X {
  abstract override def run = {
    println("hi")
    super.run
  }
}

class A extends X {
  def run = println("bye")
}

object Z extends A with Y
```

`Z.run` will print

```
hi
bye
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create base abstract class:

```
abstract class A {
  def run
}
```

Then extend it with X or Y:

```
trait X extends A /* OR trait Y extends A */ {
  def run
}

trait Y /*extends A*/ extends X {
  abstract override def run = {
    println("hi")
    super.run
  }
}
```

Then move `Z.run` to super class:

```
class S extends A {
  def run = println("bye")
}

object Z extends S with X with Y {
  //override def run = println("bye")
}

Z.run
// hi
// bye
```

Comment: I think @Kolmar's solution gets the same result with less traits/classes. Nonetheless, thank you. :)